# How to call functions from *.min.js on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, i'm using this image cropper https://github.com/bupy7/jquery-cropbox, in file jquery.cropbox.min.js there function to zoomin/zoomout when mousewheel event. I want to add 2 buttons zoomin/zoomout and call that functions on mouse click, how i can call that fucntions?

```
am = function (aB) {
        if (aB.deltaY > 0) {
            m()
        } else {
            D()
        }
        aB.preventDefault ? aB.preventDefault() : (aB.returnValue = false)
    },
    m = function () {
        al *= 1.01;
        var aC = e.width * al,
            aB = e.height * al;
        g(aC, aB);
        U(k.position().left, k.position().top)
    },  
    D = function () {
        var aC = al;
        al *= 0.99;
        var aD = e.width * al,
            aB = e.height * al;
        if (aD >= k.width() && aB >= k.height()) {
            g(aD, aB);
            U(k.position().left, k.position().top)
        } else {
            al = aC
        }
    },
```

am - calling when mousewheel, m - it is zoonin, D - it is zoomout. I dont know how to call this functions on button click. Thanks.

Comment: You can refer to this link https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These functions are protected - its not possible to call them outside of plugin.
You can request author to add API methods for them.